# sql server string concat using '+'

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

```
declare @temp_table table(name varchar(100),space_used_mb int,ln int identity(1,1))
insert into @temp_table select name,
convert(decimal(12,2),round(fileproperty(a.name,'SpaceUsed')/128.000,2))as [SPACE_USED_MB]
from dbo.sysfiles a
select 'dbcc shrinkfile(' + name + space_used_mb + ')' from @temp_table
```

I am trying to generate dynamic script for secondary files but I get following error

> Msg 245, Level 16, State 1, Line 8
>   Conversion failed when converting the varchar value ')' to data type int.

Comment: If you use the CONCAT function, you don't have to worry about conversions, it converts everything to varchar for you.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not entirely sure what you are trying to achieve (since you'll only print DBCC commands).

But since your question title is about concatenating a string, here is your issue: `space_used_mb` is a `DECIMAL` and you need to convert it to a `VARCHAR` (or `NVARCHAR`) value before you concatenate it.

```
...
select 'dbcc shrinkfile(' + name + CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), space_used_mb) + ')' from @temp_table
```

Additionally, to have a "valid" DBCC SHRINKFILE command, you're also missing a comma:

```
...
select 'dbcc shrinkfile(' + name + ',' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), space_used_mb) + ')' from @temp_table
```

Answer (score 1):

Also Try this..

```
declare @temp_table table
(
    name varchar(100),
    space_used_mb DECIMAL(10,2),
    ln int identity(1,1)
);


insert into @temp_table (name, space_used_mb)
select name,
       convert(decimal(12,2)
       ,round(fileproperty(a.name,'SpaceUsed')/128.000,2))as [SPACE_USED_MB]
from dbo.sysfiles a

select 'DBCC shrinkfile(' + name +','
               + CAST(space_used_mb AS NVARCHAR(100))
               + ')'+ CHAR(10) +'GO' from @temp_table
```

**RESULT**

```
DBCC shrinkfile(master,2.94)
GO
DBCC shrinkfile(mastlog,0.68)
GO
```

**Note**

Why would you shrink your log file this much? this is a bad bad very bad practice, It means every time sql server wants to write logs it will end up increasing the size of log file, just to write few more logs, and will create new VLFs and you will end up with hundreds of VLFs.

By default if sql server has 4 VLFs when your Logfile is upto 64MB, 8 VLFs when logfile is greater than 64MB and less than 1GB and 16 VLFs when LogFile is more than 1 GB.

If the size of log file is not enough and you have allowed auto growth, Sql Server will increase the size of logfile when it need to write logs and the file isnt big enough, This will create new VLFs every time it increases the size of log file. You want to avoid this situation. As managing less log files Vs managing 100s log file you are making your sql server work hard unnecessary. Not good not good at all.